# How to cancel Retrofit request when one request is still executing?

Tags: android, retrofit

Is there any way to find if one request is still executing in retrofit or not?
I want to cancel request if one request is still executing and isn't completed yet.

```
// fetch Results
private void fetchResults(CharSequence s) {

    if (s.toString().length() > 3){
        mSearchResult.clear();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
        hashMap.put("q", s.toString());

        PrefManager pref = new PrefManager(SearchActivity.this);
        String token = pref.getAuthenticationToken();

        Call<AppointmentsModel> call = mAPIService.getResults("Token " + token, hashMap);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<AppointmentsModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AppointmentsModel> call, Response<AppointmentsModel> response) {
                List<Result> resultList = response.body().getResult();

                mSearchResult.addAll(resultList);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                showNoSearchResults();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AppointmentsModel> call, Throwable t) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onFailureRetrofit: " + t.toString());
            }
        });
    }else{
        showNoSearchResults();
    }
}
```

I want to cancel call whenever one request is already working. Can you tell me where should i do the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make it as global:

```
Call<AppointmentsModel> call;

public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {
if(call != null && call.isExecuted()) {
  call.cancel();
}else{
//Your network call
}
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where should i do the same? For the results i required, By looking at the code above?

Comment: before calling the second request

Comment: and how to find if its first request or second?

Comment: why you want to cancel the request??any specific reason?

Comment: Because it populates my recyclerview twice, since one request was on the way and other request hits API again, which i don't want.

Comment: But i am initializing call inside fetchResults();

Comment: whenever some text is changed in editText, it calls fetchResults();

Comment: add progressdialog and restrict the user to enter the next char

Comment: finally i found the solution i think. try like this.. i have updated the above answer

Comment: In your above answer where should i initialize call?

Comment: initialize global variable in same class.